# storage issues with live boot with kali issues with or w/o persistence. installer issues too

Tags: boot, kali-linux, system-installation, live-usb, storage

okay so when i boot up my live boot with my drive (64GB) everything works fine but i only have 5.5gb left there storage or so. When i go to /run folder there is 1.1gb left there when i go to /run/live folder there is only 1.1gb left there. then i open /run/live/medium folder and there is 53gb left there or so. i dont know how to make my storage just be there when i boot it its been days and i finally decided to make a acc here because i have researched so much about mounting and block devices etc. and nothing. i want to use it with persistence because i have like 500gb storage but all that storage is inside the media/kali/--***** folder (just random numbers and letters for the **). also if i run the installer it wont go past detect and mount phase says something about my flash drive seems its been pulled out.

im so tired of trying to figure this out i have formated my drive more than once reinstalled the iso etc. and its still same issue. CAN A EXPERT PLEASE HELP ME??? also this may be helpful that when i run `sudo apt-get update` it runs for a few then i get this

`Conflicting distribution: file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot Release (expected kali-last-snapshot but got kali-rolling)`

(yes i made sure i downloaded the right iso image. i checked that more than anything)

my end goal is to either use kali with persistence or install it on my hard drive can anyone help pls

thank you hope to hear from someone soon

---

I have the same issue with my mint drive It’s something to do with the way my disk is mounted I believe thank you though.

Comment: If you're this unsure the best piece of advice I can give you is not to run Kali. Instead use a friendly distribution such as Mint or Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt update (without -get)

As in the documentation:

kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
kali@kali:~$
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade -y
kali@kali:~$